# "get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given"

Tags: php, jquery, json

Got this error:

```
login: demo
password: ****
[AJAX] Invalid JSON - Server reponse is: 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in <b>C:\wamp\www\examples\json-rpc\json-rpc.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in <b>C:\wamp\www\examples\json-rpc\json-rpc.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in <b>C:\wamp\www\examples\json-rpc\json-rpc.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":"2","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid Request: no method"}}
```

In the actual file it's referring to it says

```
// return object field if exist otherwise return default value
function get_field($object, $field, $default) {
  $array = get_object_vars($object);
  if (isset($array[$field])) {
    return $array[$field];
  } else {
    return $default;
  }
}
```

Can I just change it to "get_string_vars"? Or does it have to stay an object to do with the passwords? I'm a bit of a noob, just working on a project, thanks.

Comment: How are you calling `get_field`?  Maybe you need to call `json_decode()` somewhere first?

Comment: Hi, the whole code is here: http://pastebin.com/1VUWUDFa - I'm not very good at php or jquery.  However, I believe it to be something to do with inputting the string when it's supposed to be an object maybe

Comment: `get_object_vars()` converts object to array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `get_field()` an *object* not a string.

You probably need to do something like:

```
$object = json_decode($input);
$result = get_field($object, $field, $default);
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would I implement that into the sample I showed you. Thanks.

Comment: @X45Gunnerzzz: Looks like you already are: `$json = json_decode($input);`.  Just pass `$json` instead of `$input` to `get_field()`.

Comment: Hamzat I'm still really confused. So can you put it in what I must do thanks. So you mean I put the $result = get_field... Into where just get_field was?                                                                                                  function get_field($object, $field, $default) {
  $array = get_object_vars($object);
  
  if (isset($array[$field])) {
    return $array[$field];
  } else {
    return $default;
  }
}

Comment: All you need to do is pass `$json` instead of `$input` when calling `get_field`.